# Where is the source code of a site located?

Tags: hosting, admin

I'm an enthusiast on web-technology. I want to know where does the code of a website resides? Is it hosting in all possible cases? Do usually people give access code to source code from admin panel? What if I want such functionality in my site? Will it be secure enough?

Answer (score 0):

The site's code lives on your web server. The security depends on the web server itself.

Comment: is it possible to have access to source code from admin panel in my site?

Comment: I would assume so, yes. Most applications like cpanel, give you access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on the features of your hosting environment. If they provide `ssh` or `ftp` access, then yes, you can most likely access and modify the source code of your sites. Otherwise you are at the mercy of the control panel(s) of the hosting or the admin area of your particular website.